# Connection to Python debugger failed: Accept timed out

Tags: python, pycharm

I have issues with attaching to process on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Python 2.7.15rc1. I set up system:

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

When I'm trying attach to process I get timeout error (I can see Connection to Python debugger failed: Accept timed out in event log)

```
Attaching to a process with PID=10619
/home/t/Desktop/venv/bin/python /home/t/pycharm-professional- 2018.3.4/pycharm- 
2018.3.4/helpers/pydev/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_pydevd.py --port 39311 --pid 10619
```

Process finished with exit code 0 Server stopped.

I tried to attach to process using liclipse and it worked.